# Replacing the default JQGrid alert with the Bootstrap alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

Hi has any one been able to replace the standard JQ Grid alert with the bootstrap alert? I am trying to tidy up the look and feel of my site and would like to use the Bootstrap alert with My JQ Grid.

I have had a quick search and messed around with trying some changes in my code but they haven't worked. I want to avoid editing the CSS files because I want to be able to perform updates as easily as possible.

Comment: which exactly bootstrap alert you mean? [bsAlerts](http://eltimn.github.io/jquery-bs-alerts/#example), [this one](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) and [this one](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts) [standard alert](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/alert.js) or you use some other plugin alternatively or additionally (for example [modal.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or other)? Could you describe more detailed how you imagine to implement the modal. In general one can replace `$.jgrid.showModal` and other mathods.

Comment: Hi Oleg thanks for the response I assumed the alert boxes I was seeing were Twitter Bootstrap because they looked nice. They were in fact the default browser alert ( I use Chrome ). When JQ Grid shows an Alert box for example on a Delete or If a required field has not being completed, I want it to use the Alert box of the users browser.

Comment: What I need is **the code fragment** or better jsfiddle demo which demonstrate how exactly you want to display alert. Alert in jqGrid is modal dialog which position can be changed. Do you want to display bootstrap alert in the same way?